# Store Ruby YAML results into an array

Tags: ruby, yaml

So I have an empty array and a .yml file. I have managed to output the results of that file with this code

```
puts YAML.load_file('some_yml_file.yml').inspect
```

I was wondering, how can I pull out each of the data and store them into an empty array?

Is it

```
emptyarray = []
YAML.load_file('some_yml_file.yml').inspect do |entry|
    emptyarray << entry
end
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is in the YAML file? If it's a YAML sequence (array), then `YAML.load_file` will return a Ruby array and you needn't do anything more. `inspect` is a method that returns a string representation of an object for debugging. Why you're using it in the above code is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

`YAML.load_file` returns a Ruby object corresponding to the type of data structure the YAML represents. If the YAML contains a sequence, `YAML.load_file` will return a Ruby array. You don't need to do anything further to put the data into an array, because it's already an array:

```
yaml = <<END
---
- I am
- a YAML
- sequence
END

data = YAML.load(yaml)
puts data.class
# => Array
puts data == ["I am", "a YAML", "sequence"]
# => true
```

(You'll notice that I used `YAML.load` to load the data from a string rather than a file, but the result is the same as using `YAML.load_file` on a file with the same contents.)

If the top-level structure in the YAML is not a sequence (e.g. if it's a mapping, analogous to a Ruby hash), then you will have to do additional work to turn it into an array, but we can't tell you what that code would look like without seeing your YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Change `YAML.load_file('some_yml_file.yml').inspect do |entry|` with `YAML.load_file('some_yml_file.yml').each do |entry|` and it should work as you expect it (assuming it's not a string).

If you post a sample of your data structure inside the YAML file and what you wish to extract and put in an array then that would help.